# OpenCart - How do you increase the Admin session timeout?

Tags: php, session, opencart

Currently the Admin session in OpenCart is about 30 seconds. I was wondering is there a PHP file or is there some way I can increase the timeout session for the login?

Currently I have been told this solution works but it does not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pingServer() {
    $.ajax({ url: location.href });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('pingServer()', 60000);
});
</script>
```

This file has been placed in ***admin/view/template/common/header.tpl***

Comment: This is likely to be an issue with your hosting provider. Contact them to ask if they can increase, you may also be able to configure this in cPanel if you use that software.

Comment: I use NGinx - I have full root access to my cloud server via Rackspace. It is dedicated - we manage the ubuntu php fast-fpm server ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can most likely be solved simply by changing the value of `session.gc_maxlifetime`. You can change this via .htaccess, php.ini or even in your script itself (before the `session_start()`)

Comment: How can this be done because I use NGinx - I have full root access to my cloud server via Rackspace.

Comment: Well if you want to set the timeout globally, just find your php.ini file (do a phpinfo() to show the current config which should show the php.ini path). Then edit your php.ini file setting the value to the number you want (it's in seconds, so one day would be 86400). Then save and restart your http server and that should do it

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same problem with a client and have used the above suggestion because changing session.gc_maxlifetime was not working. If the user leaves the admin page open using the above method, it will never get timed out, so I suggest adding a timeout to kill the interval:

```
(function($) {
  var interval = setInterval(pingServer, 60000);

  function pingServer() {
      $.ajax({ url: location.href });
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1440000);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: where do you add this script?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work, as a use has say, this is normal setting you can do in PHP and PHP.ini

If you not can use this try to edit the URL you call to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pingServer() {
    $.ajax({ url: "/ping.php" });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('pingServer()', 60000);
});
</script>
```

And in the file ping.php you has.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['last_ping'] = time();
?>
```

For force PHP to update you server side session cookie.

This can also be a miss config in the setting for OpenCart?

Comment: Thanks for this too. I have this in place and also the .php ini edit.

Answer (score 0):

for opencart 1.5.x just open /system/library/session.php and add this line

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',5400);//90 minute
```