# How to extend session timeout in opencart

Tags: php, session, opencart

I'm developing a website using opencart and I wanted to extend the session timeout to 1 hour. How can I extend the session timeout in opencart 3? Should I edit the session.php in system/library?

Comment: does this answer your question [OpenCart - How do you increase the Admin session timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386548/opencart-how-do-you-increase-the-admin-session-timeout)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCart - How do you increase the Admin session timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386548/opencart-how-do-you-increase-the-admin-session-timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the value of `session.gc_maxlifetime`. You can change this via `.htaccess`, `php.ini` or even in your `script` itself (before the `session_start()`)

I hope working well...